# Baggage for international flight with domestic connection

Tags: customs-and-immigration, luggage, japan, international-travel, domestic-travel

I have a flight coming up in June; this will be my first international flight with checked baggage. I will be flying with Air Canada from Atlanta (ATL) to Toronto (YYZ) and then from Toronto (YYZ) to Tokyo (HND). From Tokyo (HND) I'll be flying to Osaka (ITM) with another airline, All Nippon Airways.

My question is will I need to pick up my checked baggage either at YYZ or at HND recheck, or will it be transferred automatically? The whole trip is on a single ticket purchased through Air Canada.

I've been told that I will only need to pick up my checked baggage at Tokyo (HND) and then recheck them with ANA. If this is so, do I go through customs before checking in with ANA?

Comment: I purchased single ticket through Canadian Air. They set up the domestic airline change with ANA.

Comment: My half-answer is that you wont need to pick it up in Toronto. I've connected from Atlanta there many times and they always transferred the luggage. No idea about the Japan segment but I *suspect* you will pick up your luggage, take it though customs and then recheck it. That is the usual process for *other* similar itineraries.

Answer (score 1):

ANA has [a page about the transit procedures at Haneda](http://www.ana.co.jp/wws/japan/e/asw_common/departure/airport/map.html?c=hnd#anchor003) (complete with a YouTube video!) which shows that when transiting international to domestic you must pick up your baggage (to pass customs) and then drop it at the domestic baggage counter before passing through the security check for connecting passengers. This is all done in the international terminal, you then take an airside shuttle bus to the domestic terminal.

Answer (score 0):

You will collect your bag at your first point of entry into Japan. You will present it for a customs inspection (and about 1 in 10 times, that involves someone actually looking inside your suitcase and your bags, it is not like inspections in many countries that are just xray machines or nothing).

After the inspection you will find yourself inside Japan in the international arrivals area. Arriving at Haneda, if you turn right there is a domestic check in area at the far end of the corridor, they will take your bag and issue you with your onward boarding pass. Then behind you is security and a bus to the domestic terminal.

Unlike some other countries, your bag will not even be tagged to the final destination; that is, the domestic airport inside Japan will not be printed on the luggage routing label. Only the first airport in Japan (HND) will be printed on the luggage label.

You will not need to collect your bag for an international-international transit through Toronto. It will be transferred through this airport automatically to Haneda.